# static div on scaled img

Tags: html, css, scale

Is it possible to adress only the image (*id* doesn't work because it includes the code between the brackets), to get scaled when hovered? Div + text should stay the same size.
I tried to scale the div + text in the other way round (1/1.1=0.9). But it wobbles, when the mouse leaves the area.

```css
.center {
 position: absolute; 
}

.scrolldownbutton {
    background-color: green;
    position: relative; /* absolute um ueber Text zu schweben*/
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
 line-height: 300px;
 transition: all .5s ease;
}

.scrolldownbutton:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1);
}

.rahmen {
 border: 2px solid yellow;
 margin: 5%;
 height: 90%;
}

.rahmen:hover {
 transition: all .5s ease;
 transform: scale(0.9);
}

.text {
 margin: -10%;
 font-size: 300%;
 color: white;
}


#newYork {
 background-image: url('http://www.travelersjoy.com/images/planning/destinations/new-york-city/newyork1.jpg');
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <div id="newYork" class="scrolldownbutton">
    <div class="rahmen">
      <p class="text">New York</p>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```